# Python File IO - building dictionary and finding max value

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io, split, max

Problem is to return the name of the event that has the highest number of participants in this text file:

```
#Beyond the Imposter Syndrome 
32 students 
4 faculty 
10 industries 
#Diversifying Computing Panel
15 students 
20 faculty 
#Movie Night 
52 students
```

So I figured I had to split it into a dictionary with the keys as the event names and the values as the sum of the integers at the beginning of the other lines. I'm having a lot of trouble and I think I'm making it too complicated than it is.

This is what I have so far:

```
def most_attended(fname):
    '''(str: filename, )'''
    d = {}
    f = open(fname)
    lines = f.read().split(' \n')
    print lines
    indexes = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if lines[i].startswith('#'):
            event = lines[i].strip('#').strip()
            if event not in d:
                d[event] = []
            print d
            indexes.append(i)
            print indexes
        if not lines[i].startswith('#') and indexes !=0:
            num = lines[i].strip().split()[0]
            print num 
            if num not in d[len(d)-1]:
                d[len(d)-1] += [num]
    print d

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

def load_data(file_name):
    events = defaultdict(int)
    current_event = None
    for line in open(file_name):
        if line.startswith('#'):
            current_event = line[1:].strip()
        else:
            participants_count = int(line.split()[0])
            events[current_event] += participants_count
    return events


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage:\n\t{} <file>\n'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    else:
        events = load_data(sys.argv[1])
        print('{}: {}'.format(*max(events.items(), key=itemgetter(1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    docText = f.read()

eventsList = []

#start at one because we don't want what's before the first #
for item in docText.split("#")[1:]:
    individualLines = item.split("\n")
    #get the sum by finding everything after the name, name is the first line here
    sumPeople = 0
    #we don't want the title
    for line in individualLines[1:]:
        if not line == "":
            sumPeople += int(line.split(" ")[0]) #add everything before the first space to the sum
    #add to the list a tuple with (eventname, numpeopleatevent)
    eventsList.append((individualLines[0], sumPeople))

#get the item in the list with the max number of people
print(max(eventsList, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Essentially you first want to split up the document by `#`, ignoring the first item because that's always going to be empty. Now you have a list of events. Now for each event you have to go through, and for every additional line in that event (except the first) you have to add that lines value to the sum. Then you create a list of tuples like `(eventname) (numPeopleAtEvent)`. Finally you use max() to get the item with the maximum number of people.

This code prints `('Movie Night', 104)` obviously you can format it to however you like

Answer (score 0):

Similar answers to the ones above.

```
result = {}         # store the results
current_key = None  # placeholder to hold the current_key

for line in lines:
    # find what event we are currently stripping data for
    # if this line doesnt start with '#', we can assume that its going to be info for the last seen event
    if line.startswith("#"):
        current_key = line[1:]
        result[current_key] = 0
    elif current_key:
        # pull the number out of the string
        number = [int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()]
        # make sure we actually got a number in the line
        if len(number) > 0:
           result[current_key] = result[current_key] + number[0]

print(max(result, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

This will print "Movie Night".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a dictionary and maybe make it a little simpler if just using lists:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l.strip() for l in lines if l[0] != '#'] # remove comment lines and '\n'
    highest = 0
    event = ""
    for l in lines:
        l = l.split()
        if int(l[0]) > highest:
            highest = int(l[0])
            event = l[1]

print (event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description says that you want to find the event with highest number of participants. I tried a solution which does not use list or dictionary.

Ps: I am new to Python.

```
bigEventName = ""
participants = 0

curEventName = ""
curEventParticipants = 0

# Use RegEx to split the file by lines
itr = re.finditer("^([#\w+].*)$", lines, flags = re.MULTILINE)

for m in itr:
    if m.group(1).startswith("#"):
        # Whenever a new group is encountered, check if the previous sum of 
        # participants is more than the recent event. If so, save the results. 
        if curEventParticipants > participants:
            participants = curEventParticipants
            bigEventName = curEventName

        # Reset the current event name and sum as 0
        curEventName = m.group(1)[1:]
        curEventParticipants = 0
    elif re.match("(\d+) .*", m.group(1)):
        # If it is line which starts with number, extract the number and sum it
        curEventParticipants += int(re.search("(\d+) .*", m.group(1)).group(1))

# This nasty code is needed to take care of the last event
bigEventName = curEventName if curEventParticipants > participants else bigEventName

# Here is the answer
print("Event: ", bigEventName)
```